# Auth request with node.js request module and special characters

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, request, authorization

I am having problems when authorizing a user with special characters in the password. I have tried several options, and I am not fully confortable with any of them. The code is this (all in UTF-8):

```
var user = 'myuser';
var password = 'ºººººº';

var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv = new Iconv('latin1', 'utf-8');
//password = iconv.convert(password).toString();

var request = require('request');
var options = {
    uri: 'http://myhost/auth',
    auth: {
        user: user,
        pass: password
    }
};

request.get(options, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error %j', err);
    } else if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.error('Error, status code %d', resp.statusCode);
    } else {
        console.log('Success!');
    }
});

console.log('Password length is %d bytes', Buffer.byteLength(password));
```

This is returning:

```
Password length is 12 bytes
Error, status code 401
```

When I uncomment the encoding conversion (5th line), I get:

```
Password length is 24 bytes
Success!
```

But I don't understand why I need to convert from "latin1" to "utf8", when the password is already in UTF-8. When I convert the whole file to ISO-8859-15, I get (with and without conversion):

```
Password length is 18 bytes
Error, status code 401
```

and:

```
Password length is 36 bytes
Error, status code 401
```

I have also tried (with same results):

```
request.get("http://" + user + ":" + password + "@myhost/auth", ...
```

and:

```
var options = {
    uri: 'http://myhost/auth',
    auth: user' + ':' + password
};
```

But this DOES work (without conversion):

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://myhost/auth',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(user + ':' + password).toString('base64')
    }
};
```

I would like to authorizate without that ugly conversion from "latin1" to "utf8" and that Buffer handling, is that possible?

Comment: Did you resolve this situation? I'm with a similar problem.

Comment: The problem come when mixing characters and bytes. For example:
'☃'.length = 1;
Buffer.byteLength('☃') == 3;
new Buffer('☃').length == 3;
To avoid problems with encodings, the best way is to use always Buffers, that can take a string in constructor, and are based on bytes, not characters. By default, encoding in Buffers are utf-8, but also accept ascii, ucs2, base64 and binary.